# Way to remove a body's headers in a multipartentity in http client

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, mime

With this snippet I am creating a `MultiPartEntity` with a `StringBody` inside. The problem is that the *Content-Type* and *Content-Transfer-Encoding* are being set and I cannot find a way to remove them.

```
MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
entity.addPart("filename", new StringBody("restore.zip",
                ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY));
```

I am obviously adding `ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY` as the *Content-Type* but even if I do:

```
entity.addBinaryBody("filename", "restore.zip".getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

I still get a default *Content-Type*.

Is there possibly any way to remove these headers inside a body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The `MultipartEntityBuilder` has a method to set the mode used.

```
entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
```